# GetLength и двумерный массив - странное поведение

Tags: c#, массивы

Не могу понять, почему происходит следующее:

```
int[,] name = new int[,]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

Если производим подсчет элементов в первой группе, то получаем 2.

```
Console.WriteLine(name.GetLength(0));
```

Если в параметрах указываем вторую группу, результат уже будет совсем другой: количество элементов в группе - 3.

```
Console.WriteLine(name.GetLength(1));
```

Почему так происходит, и как корректно и правильно подсчитать количество элементов каждой отдельной группы? В данном случае у нас результат при подсчете первой и второй группы разный.

А вот если добавить еще одну группу, и в параметрах GetLength указать значение 2, то код и вовсе перестает выполняться, вылетает ошибка.

Comment: потому что ваш массив - это матрица 2х3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

то, что вы объявляете - это 2-мерный массив, то есть матрица. Матрица всегда прямоугольная, то есть для каждой строки одинаковое количество столбцов.

Вот это - `name.GetLength(0)` - возвращает количество строк в матрице - у вас их две.

Вот это - `name.GetLength(1)` - возвращает количество столбцов - у вас их три.

Вот это - `name.GetLength(2)` - пытается обратиться к третьему измерению, но у вас матрица 2-мерная, потому получаете ошибку.

То, что вам надо, называется зубчатый (или ступенчатый) массив. То есть вам нужна не матрица, а массив массивов. Объявить его можно так

```
int[][] name = { new[]{ 1, 2, 3 }, new[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
```

Работать с ним можно так

```
// количество подмассивов в массиве - 2
Console.WriteLine(name.Length);

// количество элементов в первом массиве - 3
Console.WriteLine(name[0].Length);

// количество элементов во втором массиве - 4
Console.WriteLine(name[1].Length);
```

Вывод очевиден

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: Спасибо господа всем за примеры и разъяснения! Иногда по вечерам копаю, вот наконец с массивами по немного начинаю понимать )))

Comment: @Мистер если проблема решена и какой то из ответов вам помог, не забудьте поставить галочку.

Comment: @Мистер кого не видно? Галку? Она вроде всегда присутствует, независимо от репутации.

Comment: @Мистер другое дело :)

Comment: Все отлично! :)

Answer (score 0):

`name.GetLength(0)` возвращает количество подмассивов в себе

`name.GetLength(1)` возвращает количество элементов в подмассивах (количество этого `{ 1, 2, 3 }`)

Comment: Как мне подсчитать во второй группе количество элементов, или если группы три и более? Например, здесь две группы: { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3 }

Comment: @Мистер, при текущем объявлении - в группах **всегда одинаковое количество** элементов. Поэтому достаточно смотреть значение `.GetLength(1)`

Comment: Кажется я понял, я попросту и не могу сделать так { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3, 4 } в Visual Studio, соответственно, код правильный, я всё понял - плечи везде должны быть равными, так? А если я хочу сделать не равными, и количество подмассивов и элементов мне неизвестно? Немного изучаю C# время от времени, по чуть-чуть. Спасибо!

Comment: @Мистер именно!

Comment: @Мистер, тогда объявлять массив надо не `[,]` а `[][]`

Comment: int[][] name =
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
}; так не получается, видимо, я что-то тут не понимаю

Comment: @Мистер, [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Comment: Понемногу начинаю осваивать массивы, спасибо за разъяснения, примеры и ссылки! )))